# Call Python From Bat File And Get Return Code

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm looking for a way to call a python script from a batch file and getting a return code from the python script.  Confusing I know, but it's based on a system that's currently in use.  I'd re-write it, but this way would be much, much quicker.

So:

```
Bat ---------------------> Python
     * call python file *

Bat <--------------------------------- Python
      * python does a load of work *
      * and returns a return code  *
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The windows shell saves the return code in the `ERRORLEVEL` variable:

```
python somescript.py
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

In the python script you can exit the script and set the return value by calling `exit()`:

```
exit(15)
```

In older versions of python you might first have to import the `exit()` function from the `sys` module:

```
from sys import exit
exit(15)
```

Comment: Errorlevel is only a pseudo-variable, it isn't actually anywhere in the environment.

Comment: This will NOT work if %ERRORLEVEL% variable already exists. Python will not overwrite it in that case (but does return the correct code - it will just be hidden by the variable!).

Comment: @fmuecke I don't see what you mean. I catch the return from different python calls using %ERRORLEVEL%. Different values on %ERRORLEVEL% from the different python scripts

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
import os
os._exit(ret_value)
```

You should also check:

- [sys.exit()](http://bytes.com/groups/python/585533-sys-exit-versus-raise-systemexit)

Comment: And thanks to you, both of your answers were correct, I just needed the other side to it from the bat file as well.  Thanks again.

Comment: I prefer the use of `sys.exit()`. for instance when writing a script to be run on a Visual Studio build process, and you want to display script output on the Build Output window. the `os._exit()` command does not allow you to see python's 'stdout'.

*Bottom line*: `sys.exit()` can be more robust than `os._exit()` in some cases. whenever one doesn't behave as expected consider user the other method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this batch script for this:

```
@echo off

REM     %1 - This is the parameter we pass with the desired return code for the Python script that will be captured by the ErrorLevel env. variable.  
REM     A value of 0 is the default exit code, meaning it has all gone well. A value greater than 0 implies an error
REM     and this value can be captured and used for any error control logic and handling within the script
   
set ERRORLEVEL=
set RETURN_CODE=%1

echo (Before Python script run) ERRORLEVEL VALUE IS: [ %ERRORLEVEL% ]
echo.

call python -c "import sys; exit_code = %RETURN_CODE%; print('(Inside python script now) Setting up exit code to ' + str(exit_code)); sys.exit(exit_code)"

echo.
echo (After Python script run) ERRORLEVEL VALUE IS: [ %ERRORLEVEL% ]
echo.
```

And when you run it a couple of times with different return code values you can see the expected behaviour:

```
PS C:\Scripts\ScriptTests> & '\TestPythonReturnCodes.cmd' 5

(Before Python script run) ERRORLEVEL VALUE IS: [ 0 ]

(Inside python script now) Setting up exit code to 5

(After Python script run) ERRORLEVEL VALUE IS: [ 5 ]

PS C:\Scripts\ScriptTests> & '\TestPythonReturnCodes.cmd' 3

(Before Python script run) ERRORLEVEL VALUE IS: [ 0 ]

(Inside python script now) Setting up exit code to 3

(After Python script run) ERRORLEVEL VALUE IS: [ 3 ]

PS C:\Scripts\ScriptTests
```