# Cannot Get The Python Return Code In Bat File (Updated)

Tags: python, batch-file, return-value

I need additional clarification about the question here:
[Call Python From Bat File And Get Return Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013246/3865171).
I do not have the reputation to write my comment there so I am posting a new question.

My Batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off
start H:\PPython_2.7.5.1\App\python H:\PPython_2.7.5.1\App\checker_task.py
@echo %ERRORLEVEL% > H:\PPython_2.7.5.1\App\output.txt
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

I am calling a python script which is syntactically and semantically correct and it returns either 0 or 1. The problem is that the `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable is not influenced by the return value of the Python script. One comment of the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1013293/3865171) from the original question says:

"This will NOT work if %ERRORLEVEL% variable already exists. Python will not overwrite it in that case (but does return the correct code - it will just be hidden by the variable!)."

This is not very clear to me and I cannot find what is wrong. What I want is to be able to return 0 or 1 from Python and based on it to exit the Batch file successfully or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be in the same instance of CMD to get the correct errorlevel.
Try without the `start` :

```
@echo off
H:\PPython_2.7.5.1\App\python H:\PPython_2.7.5.1\App\checker_task.py
echo %ERRORLEVEL% > H:\PPython_2.7.5.1\App\output.txt
```