# How to handle exit code in batch script?

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a batch script which eventually runs two python file (one after another), but I am unable to handle the exit code from one workflow to another. Due to which my batch script is failing

**batch file snippet:**

```
@echo off
echo "Starting the automation Script"
cd "C:\Desktop\AutoImpement\"
echo "running the loging"
    start python login.py
    start python OrderTicket.py             
pause
```

**login script:**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Desktop\AutoImpement\ChromeDriver")
browser.get('https://localhost:8080/login/#') 
browser.find_element_by_id(“Login”).send_keys(“<userName>”)
browser.find_element_by_id (“Password”).send_keys(“password”)
browser.find_element_by_id(“submit”).click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_id(“ItemName”).send_keys(“test”)
browser.find_element_by_id (“Quantity”).send_keys(“5”)
browser.find_element_by_id(“Address”).send_keys(“Test”)
browser.find_element_by_id(“submitOrder”).click()
time.sleep(3)
browser.quit()
```

**Verify the Order Script**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Desktop\AutoImpement\ChromeDriver")
browser.get('https://localhost:8080/OrderDetails') 
browser.find_element_by_id(“SreachOrder”).send_keys(“test”)
browser.find_element_by_id(“findOrder”).click()
time.sleep(3)
browser.quit()
```

When I run the batch file, only the login script is running successfully but the control is not shifting to the next script which verifies the order from the first file. I tried with sending the exit code from the python by changing the following but didn't work.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
try:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Desktop\AutoImpement\ChromeDriver")
    browser.get('https://localhost:8080/login/#') 
    browser.find_element_by_id(“Login”).send_keys(“<userName>”)
    browser.find_element_by_id (“Password”).send_keys(“password”)
    browser.find_element_by_id(“submit”).click()
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.find_element_by_id(“ItemName”).send_keys(“test”)
    browser.find_element_by_id (“Quantity”).send_keys(“5”)
    browser.find_element_by_id(“Address”).send_keys(“Test”)
    browser.find_element_by_id(“submitOrder”).click()
    time.sleep(3)
    exit(0)
except:
    print("Error Occured")
    exit(1)
finally:
browser.quit()
```

Comment: this will answer your question I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013246/call-python-from-bat-file-and-get-return-code

Comment: Try to replace `start python ...` by `python ...`, because `start` just starts the given command line but does not wait for it to finish. And replace `cd ...` by `cd /D ...` to also change the drive in case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above case in your batch file. Both the Scripts will run simultaneously. 
Remove Start 
python login.py
python OrderTicket.py

The Second will run only after first is complete.

Comment: I suppose that adding at least the `/Wait` option to `Start` would also work for the first if not both of the `python` commands.